# use e.preventDefault(); not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to prevent an input type file from opening the 'file selection window'. 
But it throws this error: Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function while the 'file selection window' still is open.

Here is my code.

**html code:**

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="images[]" class="fbtn" onclick="check_img(this)" id="file_input"/>
```

**jquery code:**

```
function  check_img(e){
    var  len = $('.user_zs_close').length;
    if(4 < len){
        var  over_img = $('#user_zs').data('img_over');
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(over_img);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `onclick="check_img(event)`

Comment: @A.Wolff,thank you for your advise,it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a function for the whole thing.

```
$('.fbtn').on("click", function(e) {
        var  len = $('.user_zs_close').length;
        if(4 < len){
            var  over_img = $('#user_zs').data('img_over');
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(over_img);
            return false;
        }
}
```